# PHP Form to create a Jira issue is not working

Tags: php, html, api, jira, jira-rest-api

I am a beginner regarding working with php and api. What I am trying to do is create a new Jira issue using the Jira Rest Api. It is my first project of this type.
I will post bellow the code from my 2 pages. I can't figure out what is my problem. 
I mention I already tested the api using Advanced REST client (basically same tool as POSTMAN) and when I do it there it works, on my site it doesn't. I mention that "JIRA PLACEHOLDER" is replaced by the actual jira instance in my code.

Jira-create-issues.php

```
<?php
    $base64_usrpwd = base64_encode($_POST['user'].':'.$_POST['pass']);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://JIRA-PLACEHOLDER/jira/rest/api/2/issue/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                                                'Authorization: Basic '.$base64_usrpwd)); 

    $arr['project'] = array( 'key' => 'TEST');
    $arr['summary'] = $_POST['summary'];
    $arr['description'] = $_POST['description'];
    $arr['issuetype'] = array( 'name' => $_POST['type']);

    $json_arr['fields'] = $arr;

    $json_string = json_encode ($json_arr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
?>
```

And the code for jira-create-issue.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Create Issue</h1>
    <form id="create-form">
        Summary: <input type="text" name="summary" id="summary" value=""/>
        Description: <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="" />
        Issue Type: <input type="text" name="type" id="type" value=""/>
        Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value=""/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value=""/>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Create Issue"/>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
$('#button').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "jira-create-issue.php",
       data: $('#create-form').serialize(),
       success: function(data){
          alert(data);
       },
       dataType: "html"
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting this error in your console? `jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/~/Desktop/create.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: Hey! No I am not getting this error because I installed XAMPP and I use it to run my local host. Without it yes I would get that error.

Comment: Could you please, provide responce from jira?

Comment: Hey, When I try to create the issue using this PHP Form, I am not getting any answer. The only thing that happens is that the site shows me an empty pop-up. I made a screenshot which you can see here: https://imgur.com/2tPdmvW
When I create it using the Advanced REST client software (similar to POSTMAN) and the Jira api  it works and it creates the new issue, so it must be a problem in the way I wrote the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
*After looking at your code more deeply, it's working as it should...
One thing you can try is to publish it to a server. It could be that Jira doesn't allow you calling them from your localhost.
That's all I could do. Your front end works (tested it, also without my additions. Obviously style.css and jquery needs to be properly referenced). Your backend seems correct, it takes the fields and maps them correctly. So the error must be in that Jira doesnt respond on the endpoint you are calling them on...good luck!*

No submit button? (type=submit)

Change

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Create Issue"/>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Create Issue"/>
```

If this is not working, try looking at your console for JavaScript errors? Especially at the POST.

You also forgot the form action. Try adding that ;-)

```
<form id="create-form" action="Jira-create-issues.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: I tried changing the code as suggested. It sadly didn't make it work. I checked my console for logs. I got 2 errors indeed:

     `jira-create-issue.html:3 GET http://localhost/request2/jquery-2.1.4.js 
     net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
     jira-create-issue.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at jira-create-issue.html:19`

Comment: I've added the jquery-2.1.4.js file into the web page root, the errors disappeared from the console however the submit is still not functional.

Comment: Also changing it from "button" to "submit" can't be the solution because I am declaring the button a little bit below and what it should do upon click  :(

Comment: I added a comment to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the edits. You are right I forgot that. Shouldn't I use "post" for method since I am trying to create a new issue? However I tried both get and post and it still didn't work. :(

Comment: Hi @MariaMaria. Yes you are right. Actually you are capturing the post submit properly. I ran your code locally and the front end part has no errors. If you clear out the Jira-stuff in your jira issue creating file and input print_r($_POST); the alert will show all data you POSTed to the PHP file. So far so good.

Comment: If you comment out all code in your Jira php file and add 
  echo $_POST['summary'];
    echo $_POST['description'];
    echo $_POST['type'].'<br>';
    echo $_POST['user'].'<br>';
    echo $_POST['pass'].'<br>';

instead, the popup (alert) will show the content. So your form is working.

But you probably need to wrap your Jira call in a If POST submit as well as map the fields in the post to the Jira types. I dont have Jira locally so I can't test it. Will make you a suggestion anyway.

Comment: Regarding your updated comment: "Your backend seems correct, it takes the fields and maps them correctly. So the error must be in that Jira doesnt respond on the endpoint you are calling them on" 
The creation works using the Advanced REST client tool and the api for the jira instance, so it must be a problem in my jira-create-issue.php file.

Comment: Again I would not do that from localhost, as the "from" is unknown.

Comment: I've tried running it from //IP:host/jira-create-issue.html and I had the same problem. If you mean that I should run it from the same server as the Jira I don't think that's possible for me.

Comment: I mean you should run it from a server where you can properly curl Jira. If that doesn't work I would check out the API settings. Are your call ok? Do you have the right password? Are you trying to use an old Jira API? If you can login to Jira and check the settings, you'll probably find it there. Your code seems fine to me. Are you getting any errors on the request? Your form does work, so it must be Jira saying "no", if they are even responding.